# iPhone - use the Featured Tabbar item image with custom title

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem

I would like to use the "Featured" tabbar item image with a custom title. I have gone through the various questions on SO regarding this and looked everywhere in the SDK frameworks but could not find the PNG for this item. I am using IB to initialize the tabbar and it is a tab-based application.

Can someone please help me out, where can I get that image or if using IB, how can I use that image with a custom title.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the featured icon (or any other supplied icon) with a custom title. Apple intends those icons to only ever be used with the title it's paired with...

Apple have been quite touchy with this topic in the past, even going as far to reject one application because it's icon for "time" was too similar to Apple's icon for "Recents/History".

See here: http://tapbots.com/blog/app-store/a-well-timed-letter-of-rejection

If you start using Apple's icons, eg, the featured icon with a custom title that isn't "featured" then you're going to have trouble with the review process.

Comment: Yes, I've had issues before with toolbar buttons. But didn't know this was the case for tabbar items too! Thanks.